# Adding qfrm fails

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to run this simple piece of code (implement Excel's `YIELD()` using `qfrm` library)  in Python using `poetry`:

```py
from qfrm import Bond

def excel_yield(price, par, rate, years, freq):
    return Bond(par=par, T=years, freq=freq, cpn=rate, yld=None, price=price).yield_to_maturity()

print(excel_yield(price=62.254, par=100, rate=1.875/100, years=18, freq=2))
```

I did `poetry add qfrm` and I got this `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "fixed-income-annuity"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["pathikrit <pathikritbhowmick@msn.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
python-dateutil = "^2.8.2"
qfrm = "^0.2.0.27"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Now when I run using `poetry run python main.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pbhowmick/workspace/fixed_income_annuity/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qfrm.Bond import *
  File "/Users/pbhowmick/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fixed-income-annuity-qEcOl1hQ-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qfrm/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .Util import *
  File "/Users/pbhowmick/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fixed-income-annuity-qEcOl1hQ-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qfrm/Util.py", line 2, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Ok, so I need `yaml`? Why didn't poetry add it for me when I added `qfrm`?

I went and did this then:

```bash
poetry add pyyaml
```

But, now when I do: `poetry run python main.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pbhowmick/workspace/fixed_income_annuity/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qfrm import Bond
  File "/Users/pbhowmick/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fixed-income-annuity-qEcOl1hQ-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qfrm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .Options import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qfrm.Options'
```

Why? Didn't I just install `qfrm`?

Note: There is nothing wrong with my poetry setup because adding some other package (`python-dateutil`) works fine and when I import and use it.

Comment: Do you have a module called `qrfm` in a local folder or in your own project? Maybe there is a name clash.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of issues with `qfrm`... The short version is that it's old, broken, and unmaintained.

1. `qfrm.Options` doesn't exist, so you can safely comment it out of `qfrm.__init__.py`. See: https://github.com/pjgranahan/qfrm/issues/5
2. `qfrm.Bond` does not exist after version `0.1.1.12` and the demo on PyPI was never updated. See: https://github.com/pjgranahan/qfrm/issues/2

If you want to use `Bond`, then you have to either install `0.1.1.12` or pull that definition into the newer version as `Bond.py` and change your main import to `from qfrm.Bond import Bond`. The Bond class relies on `time.clock`, so you have to either use Python <3.8 or update it.